# Order of children added to UniformGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf

If you add a second child to a `UniformGrid` with 3 rows and 3 colomns, will it be added in the same row or to the same column? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you seriously asking this? It takes less than a minute to try it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second child is added to the same row as the first child.

Generally speaking, the `UniformGrid` adds children like you would write English text: from left to right, and when you reach the end of the line (row), start at the beginning (left) of the next line (row).